# SO Mobile Commenting Broken

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments, safari

On my iPhone 4S running iOS 5.1.1, the "add comments" link is completely broken on mobile Stack Overflow *only*.  Desktop Stack Overflow and Meta work fine (as does, I assume, the rest of SE's sites).  I have over 7,000 rep and am not on any kind of ban or probation, so I know that's not an issue.  Ack, it's just so annoying to use desktop view on an iPhone!

UPDATE:  It appears now to be limited to questions that I myself have asked on SO.

UPDATE 2: The iOS 6 beta 1 version of safari has completely disabled the commenting link and the notifications drop down in both mobile and desktop.

Comment: +1, I'm having the same experience (including your edit) on Android mobile.

Comment: Reproduced on WebOS. Expanding comments is also broken.

Comment: Repro on iOS 5.1.1.

Comment: Same here on Windows Phone 7.

Comment: @NiranjanKala this is still broken for you?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This was my bug - I created it while trying to fix accepted answer mechanics for screen readers, forgetting we had a mobile view of the voting controls.

I've consolidated the voting control code between the two views and the fix is being rolled out now.

Thanks for reporting!